# My rigid body controller stuck in middle of screen (unity)

Tags: c#, unity, rigidbody

Still working on my Star Fox clone and am changing up the camera a bit.

**The problem I keep having is my Ship gets locked in the middle of the screen and can't move while its parent (spinMe) is still moving.**

I'm working with rigidbody-ception here I have a rigidbody with in a rigidbody. Both of them move up, down, left, and right.These two are called ***spinMe*** and ***Ship***.

[image: My hierarchy]

In [this version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7hpypy9ovg)  the player is able to move until they reach the end of the screen.

What I'd like to do is have the camera move slightly as well to help ***Ship*** cover more of a bases and help with perception. *Star Fox did this as well.*

So ***spinMe*** pulls ***Ship*** around with it but for some reason that keeps ***Ship*** from moving independently while being moved around by ***spinMe***. Only when ***spinMe*** can't move any further ***Ship*** will move.

So I guess I would like to know is why can't I get my ***Ship*** to move at the same time as ***spinMe***.

**So this is the main chunk of the code for spinMe**

```
    Vector3 movementy = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * turnSpeed);
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position + movementy;
    Vector3 offset = newPos - Midpoint.position;
    transform.position = Midpoint.position + Vector3.ClampMagnitude(offset, radius);

    Vector3 movementx = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turnSpeed);
    Vector3 newPosx = transform.position + movementx;
    Vector3 offsetx = newPosx - Midpoint.position;
    transform.position = Midpoint.position + Vector3.ClampMagnitude(offsetx, radius);
```

**And this is the movement for Ship**

```
Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);
    pos.x = Mathf.Clamp01(pos.x);
    pos.y = Mathf.Clamp01(pos.y);
    transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(pos);
   Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(turnSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 
                                       turnSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0);
   moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
   rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveDirection);
```

I've tried this a variety of different ways and I believe this is my best chance of getting this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it okay what I did was I put spinMe within another object and moving that one around. I believe the whole problem had to do with the fact that spinMe is an animated object. this was a relatively simple fix as it turns out.